# Table on Web Browser not populating. Foreach loop problem?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, foreach, webbrowser-control

**Problem:** I want the pets in my database to show on the web browser. My foreach isn't giving an error but the pets are not showing up.

**Suspicion:** I'm sure it has something to do with how I am creating a new List in my HomeController, passing it into the partial in my Index, then using @model List in the _PetListView.

**Request:** Can you help me understand what I am missing?

***Pet.cs***

```csharp
namespace petShelter.Models
{
    public class Pet
    {
        [Key]
        public int PetId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public string Skill1 { get; set; }
        public string Skill2 { get; set; }
        public string Skill3 { get; set; }


        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }

        public Owner Owner { get; set; }
        public int? OwnerId { get; set; }

    }
}
```

***HomeController.cs***

```csharp
    [HttpGet("/")] 
     public IActionResult Index()
     {
      List<Pet> allPets = new List<Pet>();

      return View("Index", allPets);  
        }
```

***Index.cshtml***

```csharp
@{
    List<Pet> newPet = new List<Pet>();
    Owner newOwner = new Owner();
}

<div>
    <div>
        <partial name="_PetListView" model="newPet" />
        <partial name="_OwnerListView" model="newOwner" />
    </div>
</div>
```

***_PetListView.cshtml***

```csharp
@model List<Pet>
<div class="text-center">
    <div>
        <header>
            <h1>Pet Shelter</h1>
            <h4>These pets are looking for a good home!</h4>
            <a href="Pet">Add a new pet to the shelter</a>
        </header>
    </div>

    <div>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (Pet animal in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td><a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Pet"></a></td>
                        <td>@animal.Name Name</td>
                        <td>@animal.Type Type</td>
                        <td>@animal.Description Description</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you are passing an empty list. You have to fill it with pets.

Comment: `List<Pet> allPets = new List<Pet>();` has no pets in it.  You need to make a call to your datasource to get the pets.

Comment: @devlincarnate How would you make a call to the database? I have two pets in the database, but my queries are not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing  empty lists. You have to fill them with pets and owners.

For the start create a viewModeL

```
public class PetViewModel
{
   public List<Pet> Pets {get; set;};
  public  List <Owner> Owners {get; set;};
}
```

after this fill it

```
[HttpGet("/")] 
     public IActionResult Index()
     {
     var model = new PetViewModel 
      {
      Pets= ...your code to create a list of pets,
      Owners = ...the code to create a list of owhers
       }

      return View("Index", model);  
        }
```

and fix the views

```
Index.cshtml

@model PetViewModel



<div>
    <div id="pets">
        <partial name= "_PetListView" model= "@Model.Pets" />
     </div>

      <div id="owners">
        <partial  name ="_OwnerListView" model= "@Model.Owners" />
    </div>
</div>
```

UPDATE

For the test you can try this:

```
 var model = new PetViewModel 
      {
      Pets= new List<Pet>{ new Pet {Name="PetName", Type="PetType", Description="PetDesctription"} },
      Owners = new List<Owner> { new Owner{ FirstName="FirstName", LastName="LastName"}}
       }
```

Or if you have EF already

```
var model = new PetViewModel 
      {
      Pets= _context.Pets.ToList(),
      Owners = _context.Owners.ToList()
       }
```

Comment: -everything makes sense except when I try to define var model. It does not like that I have the PetViewModel with {Pets, Owners} inside.

Comment: This is just a sample.

Comment: Ok, so what you provided works if I wanted to create/store the instances inside the controller. But what if I have a database that already holds instances? For example, I have already created two pets. How would I query to the database to have those pets render on the page?

Comment: THAT'S IT! 
Ok, so I thought I needed to have .Include(p=>p.Pets). That's what was messing me up in my understanding.
Thank you, again, @Sergey!